# Examples of zero-dimensional commutative rings with non-discrete Spec?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra

If I'm not mistaken, if the spectrum $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ (with the Zariski topology) of a commutative ring $R$ is discrete,
then $R$ has Krull dimension zero.

Would anyone know an example of a commutative ring $R$ of Krull dimension zero whose spectrum is non-discrete? Can such a ring be also local and reduced?

Note: If I'm not mistaken: a commutative, reduced, local, von-Neumann-regular ring is a field [cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465960/a-characterization-of-commutative-rings-with-krull-dimension-zero) and its answer], hence its spectrum is a one-point space, which is discrete. So a comm, reduced, local ring with non-discrete spectrum is necessarily not von-Neumann-regular.

(Edit: As a post has pointed out, a commutative, Krull-dimension-zero, local, reduced ring is just a field.)

Comment: How about $K \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} K$, where $K$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$? I think the spectrum  is isomorphic to the Galois group of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If your ring $R$ has Krull dimension zero and is local and reduced, then it is a field. Indeed, since $R$ has dimension zero, every prime ideal is maximal, so $R$ just has one prime ideal, namely its unique maximal ideal $M$. But then the nilradical of $R$ is just $M$, so $M = 0$.

Comment: As for your question: I think something like $R = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_{2}$ should work, but I don't have the energy to verify all the details at the moment. I might post an answer later.

Answer (score 1):

spec(R) is zero dimensional if and only if it is Hausdorff and totally disconnected. So, take a non-discrete, totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space $X$ and let $R=C(X\to\mathbb{Z}_2)$ the algebra of all continuous functions $X\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ with pointwise operations.

Comment: I have a question: in your answer, why does $X = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ where $R = C(X)$?

Comment: The example should have been $C(X\to\mathbb{Z}_2)$, not $C(X\to\mathbb{C})$. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024993/spectrum-of-a-ring-homeomorphic-to-a-compact-totally-disconnected-space and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3453534/922380