Characterization of minimal prime ideals

Let $A$ a commutative ring with identity. The following are equivalent:

If $P \subset A$ is minimal prime ideal, then it is maximal.
If $P$ is prime ideal, then is minimal and maximal.
$\forall x \in A \, \exists (n, y) \in \Bbb{N} \times A : x^n(1-xy)=0$


I am trying to solve this excercise from my Commutative algebra book.
($1 \implies 2$) Let $P \subset A$ a prime ideal. It is easy to prove as a consequence of Zorn Lemma the existence of $Q \subset A$ minimal prime ideal and $m \subset A$ maximal ideal with $Q \subseteq P \subseteq m$ and by hypothesis $Q$ is maximal, so $Q = P = m$
($3 \implies 1$) Let $P$ a minimal prime ideal (which is equivalent to $A/P$ being an integral domain) and $x \in A \setminus P$. By hypothesis, there is $(n, y) \in \Bbb{N} \times A$ such that $x^n (1-xy) = 0 \implies 0 + P = x^n (1 - xy ) + P \implies 0 + P = 1 - xy + P \implies xy + P = 1 + P$, so $A/P$ is a field and then $P$ is maximal.
I have thought this proofs and I wonder if there are fine, specially the second since there I am not using the minimality of $P$.
Also, I am stuck with $(2 \implies 3)$ . My attempt was to take $x \in A$ and consider $S := \{ x^n : n \geq 0 \}$ . Then $P:= A \setminus S$ is prime and by hypothesis, it is minimal prime and maximal. Since $P$ is maximal, $A/P$ is a field and then $\exists (y,z) \in A \setminus P \times P : xy = 1 + z$ , but I am not getting anything and I do not have very idea on how to use minimality, so any possible help or advice would be appreciated.

Maybe it is what you meant, but just to be sure: In $(1\Rightarrow 2)$ you need the existence of a minimal prime ideal contained in $P$ and a maximal prime ideal containing $P$. The latter comes from the existence of maximal ideals In $R/P$, while the former comes from the existence of minimal prime ideals in $R_P = R[(R\setminus P)^{-1}]$.

For $(2) \implies (3)$, try $\text{nil}(A) = \text{Jac}(A)$.

@JonasLinssen Well, to construct them I did not think on other rings, for the minimal ideal I thought on this and the maximal ideal it is sufficent to consider the ordered set consisting on prime ideals who contain $P$ and apply Zorn.

@RHspqr Thanks for your comment! I do not see how to apply what you say, can you be more specific?

@DanielGarcía sure that works too :D Are there any further assumptions on the ring $A$?

@JonasLinssen No, only what I wrote

@DanielGarcía It turns out that my idea only works for Noethrian rings. It's better to try this :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465960/a-characterization-of-commutative-rings-with-krull-dimension-zero

@RHspqr this makes sense. I tried to make your hint into a rigorous proof for some time yesterday and always needed finitely many minimal primes in the end... That's why I was asking about further assumptions on $A$...

Suppose (2) holds, take any $x\in A$ and consider the localization $B=A_x$. Note that to show (3), it suffices to see that $A\to B$ is surjective so that there exists $y\in A$ such that its image in $B$ serves as the inverse to $x$. Consider $A\to B$ as $A$-module homomorphism. For any maximal $P\subset A$, if $x\notin P$, $A_P\to B_P$ is an isomorphism and if $x\in P$, $B_P=0$ as a ring whithout any primes.

Thanks for your answer! I have some questions if I do not bother you. Where are you using (2) ? Specially minimality, I do not see how it works here. Also, why $A_P \rightarrow B_P$ is in the first case an isomorphism and $B_P = 0 $ in the second case?

@DanielGarcía The minimality of $P$ implies that $A_P$ is a ring with just one prime. $B_P$ is the localization of $A_P$ by $x$. Localization by units changes nothing, in particular $A_P=B_P$ in the first case. For the second, any non-zero ring has at least one maximal (hence prime) ideal by Zorn.

Okay, know I understund. Only one more question, why $B_P$ has no maximal ideals?
